# HTML5 video not playing in native iOS email client (2015)

Tags: ios, html, email, video, mp4

I am trying to send an HTML email with a video embedded in the code and view it on the native email app for iOS devices. The native iOS mail app has supported HTML5 video elements and I have tested this on many occasions in the past few years.

Last week after sending a few video emails, I noticed that the media player in the native app would load, render the initial frame of the video, but not play the video. I've gone through the iOS software release history to see if there was anything that may have affected this behavior but was unsuccessful.

Below is the email

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <style></style>
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="html5-video">
  <p>THIS IS A HTML5 VIDEO</p>
  <video controls>
   <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
  </video>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional notes:
- video plays fine in other supported email environments 
- iOS supports the H.264/MP4 video file format
- the issue started occurring sometime in March or April

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you returning the proper content-type header (video/mp4), and do you have the mime type registered on your webserver?  iOS doesn't care about the extension, it simply needs to match the 'type' attribute with the response header content-type.

Comment: Yes, the video/mp4 mime type is registered on my webserver. The video content was tested and playable some time last month in iOS so I do not believe there is something wrong with server configuration. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I ran into the same issue and its related to IOS8.  See: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6800366?start=0&tstart=0 and http://www.emaildesignreview.com/html-email-coding/the-video-tag-is-missing-in-action-in-ios8-mail-2014/

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight inaccuracy in your question.

> iOS supports the file format of MP4

Almost! It actually supports *some* MP4 files, but not all of them.

You need to closely [follow the guidance that Apple issue](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html) if you want the video to play - they protect their brand by refusing to attempt to play videos that could look poor on the device...

In particular, they want you to adhere to certain conditions for bit rates, sizes, and even request that your HTTP server supports byte-range requests.

If you meet these conditions - then the video should play.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am now using a video MP4 file that is apple compliant. But these are guidelines rather than requirements. Though I appreciate the link to the resource :D

Comment: Just want to be clear that serving an apple compliant video did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: This is interesting. I have tested several videos that have previously been reported as working in email on iOS - but I just get fallback content in all cases. For example: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email

Comment: Steve - Thanks for testing on your side. I might reach out to apple to see if they can provide some enlightenment on the issue. 

If anyone else has any insights to this problem please feel free to chime in.

Comment: Check the headers being sent along with the mp4 in Safari's inspector.  Make sure it matches Apple's guidelines.  This is a separate consideration from the format and mime-type registration.

Comment: Brandon - Just to clarify, you mean to render the email HTML as a web page in Safari and check the headers there? Would you also be able to point me to Apple's guidelines on content headers. I've searched but I am unable to find it.